# Having some error while doing a react restaurant project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom, render

**RestaurantUpdate.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class RestaurantUpdate extends Component {
render() {
    console.warn(this.props.match.params.id);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Update</h1>

        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RestaurantUpdate;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
Navbar,
Nav,
Container
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './App.css';
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Routes,
Route,
Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from "./components/Home"

import RestaurantSearch from "./components/RestaurantSearch"
import RestaurantCreate from "./components/RestaurantCreate"
import RestaurantList from "./components/RestaurantList"
import RestaurantUpdate from "./components/RestaurantUpdate"
import RestaurantDetail from "./components/RestaurantDetail"
function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>
         <Navbar.Brand href="#home"><img width="75px" height="55px" src="/brand.png" alt="Brand" /></Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto" >

            <Nav.Link href="#home" ><Link to="/" style={{ color: 'yellow', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>Home</Link></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link"><Link to="/list" style={{ color: 'yellow', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>List</Link></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link"><Link to="/create" style={{ color: 'yellow', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>Create</Link></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link" ><Link to="/search" style={{ color: 'yellow', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>Search</Link></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link"><Link to="/details" style={{ color: 'yellow', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>Detail</Link></Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link"><Link to="/update" style={{ color: 'yellow', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>Update</Link></Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/list" element={<RestaurantList />} />
      <Route path="/create" element={<RestaurantCreate />} />
      <Route path="/search" element={<RestaurantSearch />} />
      <Route path="/update/:id" render={props => (
        <RestaurantUpdate {...props} />
      )} />
      <Route path="/details" element={<RestaurantDetail />} />
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
</div >
);
}

export default App;


<Route path="/update/:id" render={props => (<RestaurantUpdate {...props} />)}/>
```

I am getting error in console.
"Matched leaf route at location "/update/1" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page."

i was expecting all the params and id in the console.
The update is not displaying as well.
Can anyone tell me error.I guess there is problem with syntax due to updated version. But no sure. I am using the latest version. So kindly tell me where is the error.

Comment: does all other routes work?

Comment: @sid all other routes is working the way is it the above code. i only want to bring render function with props in the <Routh path="/update/:id" .... But it is showing error as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `react-router-dom` `v6` and above since I see element `props` in other `routes`. Also your error says it is missing element here

***Matched leaf route at location "/update/1" does not have an element***

Try with this modification

```
<Route path="/update/:id" element={<RestaurantUpdate {...props} />} />
```

Comment: I tried this. A error is showing in terminal : 'props' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `path="/update/:id"` route isn't rendering any content on the `element` prop. In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component API changed significantly, there is no longer any `component` or `render` and `children` function props and there are no longer any route props, i.e. no `location`, `match`, or `history` props. The `RestaurantUpdate` component isn't rendered, and even if it was, the `this.props.match` is undefined.

## Solution

Render the `RestaurantUpdate` component on the `element` prop and use the `useParams` hook to access the `id` path parameter.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/list" element={<RestaurantList />} />
  <Route path="/create" element={<RestaurantCreate />} />
  <Route path="/search" element={<RestaurantSearch />} />
  <Route path="/update/:id" element={<RestaurantUpdate />} />
  <Route path="/details" element={<RestaurantDetail />} />
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
</Routes>
```

Since `RestaurantUpdate` is a class component you'll need to either convert it to a React function component or create a custom `withRouter` HOC to inject the path params as a prop.

### Convert to function component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const RestaurantUpdate = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.warn(id);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Update</h1>

    </div>
  );
};

export default RestaurantUpdate;
```

### Create a `withRouter` HOC

```
import { useParams, /* other hooks */ } from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const params = useParams();
  // other hooks
  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
      {...{ params, /* other hook props */ }}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter;
```

...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withRouter from '../path/to/withRouter';

class RestaurantUpdate extends Component {
  render() {
    console.warn(this.props.match.params.id);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Update</h1>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(RestaurantUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

... however If you dont wanna go with React.FC you may use (as a quick solution) regexp over the:
`window.location.pathname.match(/\update\/(\d+)/)`

```
"/update/123".match(/\update\/(\d+)/); // ['update/123', '123', index: 1, input: '/update/123', groups: undefined]
```